# Android Jetpack Compose draw rectangle by the full height and width of its parent layout

Tags: canvas, android-jetpack-compose, draw

I am trying to draw a round rectangle based on the height and width of its parent.

The below code snippet draws the rectangle  but its not filling the whole box

```
{
    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current

    var height by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0. dp)
    }

    var width by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0. dp)
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            lc - >
                height = with(localDensity) {
                    lc.size.height.toDp()
                }
            width = with(localDensity) {
                lc.size.width.toDp()
            }
        }) {

        drawRect(size = Size(width = width.value, height = height.value), color = Color.Green)

        Column() {
            Text(

                text = "H $height",


            )
            Text(

                text = "W $width",


            )
        }

    }

}
```

I want the canvas to draw the rectangle, using the full height and width of the box, I am populating this in a grid like column and row , as below.

I don't want to use filling the *Box* layout background, I want to

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong in your code is you are converting size in px to dp while drawRect function requires `Size` which has width and height params as `Float` in `px`. Let's say your screen is 1000x1000 and density 2. When you convert to dp and get `dp.value`, this is **2f if it's 2.dp**, you can only draw 500x500 rect while your parent size is 1000x1000px

You can also do it with Modifier.onSizeChanged{} as

```
val localDensity = LocalDensity.current

var size by remember {
    mutableStateOf(Size.Zero)
}


Box(modifier = Modifier

    .onSizeChanged {
        size = localDensity.run { it.toSize() }
    }
    .drawBehind {
        drawRect(size = size, color = Color.Green)
    }

) {
}
```

If you don't need to size in any place you can draw it as below either

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .drawBehind {
        drawRect(color = Color.Green)
    }

) {
}
```

Modifier.drawBehind's param is `onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit`, has DrawScope receiver which returns size of the Composable its set to. Default size for drawRect is size from DrawScope.